# JQ Group By by Key, Merge Value, then Flatten Object

Tags: jq

With the following inputs:

```
# file1.json
{
  "uid": "1",
  "name": "jack"
}
{
  "uid": "2",
  "name": "jill"
}

# file2.json
{
  "fid": "a",
  "file": "sample1.txt",
  "uid": "1"
}
{
  "fid": "b",
  "file": "sample2.txt",
  "uid": "1"
}
{
  "fid": "c",
  "file": "sample3.txt",
  "uid": "2"
}
```

How do I go about inserting the `name` key-value pair to the object in the `file2.json`. The output I'm trying to get is as follows:

```
{
  "fid": "a",
  "file": "sample1.txt",
  "uid": "1",
  "name": "jack"
}
{
  "fid": "b",
  "file": "sample2.txt",
  "uid": "1",
  "name": "jack"
}
{
  "fid": "c",
  "file": "sample3.txt",
  "uid": "2",
  "name": "jill"
}
```

Solutions posted on [merge json objects with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254655/merge-json-objects-with-jq) and [join two json files based on common key with jq utility or alternative way from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830426/join-two-json-files-based-on-common-key-with-jq-utility-or-alternative-way-from) both seems to only return the last matching pair. See below.

```
{"uid":"1","name":"jack","fid":"b","file":"sample2.txt"}
{"uid":"2","name":"jill","fid":"c","file":"sample3.txt"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to "slurp" file1.json, e.g. by invoking jq as follows:

```
jq -n -f merge.jq --slurpfile file1 file1.json file2.json
```

where merge.jq contains:

```
INDEX($file1[]; .uid) as $dict
| inputs
| . + $dict[.uid]
```

### def INDEX

If your jq does not have INDEX/2, then simply add its def:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({}; .[$row|idx_expr|tostring] = $row);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, however, trying the above, I get the following error:
    jq: error: INDEX/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
    INDEX($file1[]; .uid) as $dict
    jq: 1 compile error

jq version is 1.5.

Comment: Now would be an excellent time to upgrade to the current version (1.6). Otherwise, please see the updated response above.

Comment: Many thanks! Upgraded to 1.6 and it works perfectly.